# How can i make a tree with linked list on every node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Im trying to make a tree where every node has a liked list. I know how to make each other, but i cant make them together. If someone can help me and give me some examle would be nice :)

Comment: Have you any sample picture or code?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Note that your question is very unclear as it stands. What sort of link? Do you mean a hyperlink so that when somebody clicks on the node, they will be taken to another part of the document with the appropriate list? Or do you mean that there is a line from the node to the list, which is placed somewhere else on the page? Or do you want the list to be in the node? Or something else?

Comment: I'm also interested in something like this, I would like to reproduce the attached image using TiKz. The blue arrows are not desired. Anyone can help?
http://imgur.com/a/tOtvF